# hasNextInt() keeps waiting for input when pressing Enter

Tags: java

First post/question here and very new to java. Trying to make a small text based movie database app. One part of it is to add a review. The problem is when I just hit [enter] when asked for a Score number [0-10] on the review, the prompt just drops one step down and keeps waiting for input. I want it to be impossible to leave this field blank. Here is what I have so far:

```
int score;
do {
  while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
    sc.next();
    System.out.print("\nInvalid input! ");
    System.out.print("Please enter a number from 0-10: ");
  }
  score = sc.nextInt();

  if (!(score >= 0 && score <= 10)) {
    System.out.print("\nInvalid input! ");
    System.out.print("Please enter a number from 0-10: ");
  }
} while (!(score >= 0 && score <= 10 ));
```

Answer (score 2):

`Scanner` is reading *tokens*, i.e. text separated by whitespaces. That means, that as long as you just press Enter, the next token hasn't even started yet.

One of the fallacies of `Scanner` is that it's so easy to use, but even easier to misuse, e.g. mishandling user input.

Example: What should happen if used enters `123 abc<enter>`? Your code will read `123` and continue, leaving `abc` in the buffer for the next prompt, which might want text and hence read the `abc` as that text. Oops!!

Most of the time, to handle bad user input, you should never use `hasNextXxx()` and `nextXxx()` methods other than `nextLine()`. It's the only way to ensure you get one answer (input) for one prompt.

So, you should do something like this:

```
int score;
for (;;) {
    System.out.print("Please enter a number from 0-10: ");
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    try {
        score = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input! Not a number.");
        continue;
    }
    if (score < 0 || score > 10) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input! Out of range.");
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: Much obliged! Will keep this in mind, never use other methods then nextLine() when handling bad user input. Also have to learn how to use the for-loop. This will come in handy in several parts of my program.